# Upload image to Facebook Page using HootSuite API

Tags: facebook, image, api, hootsuite

From what I read in the HootSuite messages API documented [here](https://hootsuite.com/developers/api/docs/messages), the message field seems to allow only text data. How do I then post an image to a Facebook Page using HootSuite API?

I want to schedule posting several images to a Facebook Page's stream with the help of HootSuite API.

Comment: @Kiquenet Sorry, brother. I ended up directly using Facebook API, as I got no satisfactory answer from HootSuite.